# Use regular expression to find string in solution

Tags: asp.net, regex, visual-studio-2010

Hi am using Visual studio search option and want to customized search using regular expression

for example I want to list all .aspx & .cs pages where word "ValidState" written and don't want to include some pages in search like "userconfig.aspx, newRegistration.aspx & addEmp.cs".

can any one tell me what will be regular expression for search ?
[image: Visual Studio IDE]

Comment: Whats the reason for down voting, is my question not valid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot exclude files from search in the search box.
Instead, you could search your solution from a command line such as cygwin using a command similar to

```
egrep '\*\*' *.aspx *.cs **/*.aspx **/*.cs | egrep -v "userconfig.aspx|newRegistration.aspx|addEmp.cs"
```